# Google analytics: Track guest checkout and registered user checkout counts

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-api, e-commerce

I have ecommerce site and i want to track how many users chose guest checkout and how many registered user purchase.

1. User clicks on "proceed to checkout". (is he already logged in or not?)
2. User decides on checkout login how to proceed (How many users choose which option?)
3. User completes checkout confirmation page and proceeds to payment provider flow
4. User completes payment and comes to thank you page OR user does not complete payment and either tries again or does not.
  5.

Is it possible with ?
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

So how can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
The Google Analytics basically works as two ways.

1. Page Tracking
2. Event Tracking

Before you track the users first find out what kind of users (i.e Free User or Registered User).

Hope you have the Google Analytics key. Please include the two functions as below.

//Track the events

trackGAEvent(eventName, eventAction, eventCategory)

{
//Do your stuff here
}

//Track the page views

trackGAPageEvent(eventName, eventAction, eventCategory)

{
//Do your stuff here
}

Based on the above functions you'll track.
```

You can call these functions accordingly.